# Creating new records in dataframe based on character

Tags: python, pandas

I have fields in a pandas dataframe like the sample data below.  The values in one of the fields are fractions with the form something/count(something).  I would like to split the values like the example output below, and create new records.  Basically the numerator and the denominator.  Some of the values even have multiple /, like count(something)/count(thing)/count(dog).  So I'd want to split that value in to 3 records.  Any tips on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sample Data:

SampleDf=pd.DataFrame([['tom','sum(stuff)/count(things)'],['bob','count(things)/count(stuff)']],columns=['ReportField','OtherField'])


Example Output:

OutputDf=pd.DataFrame([['tom1','sum(stuff)'],['tom2','count(things)'],['bob1','count(things)'],['bob2','count(stuff)']],columns=['ReportField','OtherField'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way but try this,

```
df = df.set_index('ReportField')
df = pd.DataFrame(df.OtherField.str.split('/', expand = True).stack().reset_index(-1, drop = True)).reset_index()
```

You get

```
    ReportField 0
0   tom         sum(stuff)
1   tom         count(things)
2   bob         count(things)
3   bob         count(stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way might be as following:

```
# split and stack 
new_df = pd.DataFrame(SampleDf.OtherField.str.split('/').tolist(), index=SampleDf.ReportField).stack().reset_index()
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    ReportField  level_1          0
0         tom        0     sum(stuff)
1         tom        1  count(things)
2         bob        0  count(things)
3         bob        1   count(stuff)
```

Now, combine `ReportField` with `level_1`:

```
# combine strings for tom1, tom2 ,.....
new_df['ReportField'] = new_df.ReportField.str.cat((new_df.level_1+1).astype(str))

# remove level column
del new_df['level_1']
# rename columns
new_df.columns = ['ReportField', 'OtherField']
print (new_df)
```

Output:

```
    ReportField     OtherField
0        tom1       sum(stuff)
1        tom2    count(things)
2        bob1    count(things)
3        bob2     count(stuff)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for new `DataFrame`
- reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
- add Counter to `ReportField` column with convert to `str` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)
- remove helper column `level_1` by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

---

```
OutputDf = SampleDf.set_index('ReportField')['OtherField'].str.split('/',expand=True)
                   .stack().reset_index(name='OtherField')
OutputDf['ReportField'] = OutputDf['ReportField'] + OutputDf['level_1'].add(1).astype(str)
OutputDf = OutputDf.drop('level_1', axis=1)
print (OutputDf)
  ReportField     OtherField
0        tom1     sum(stuff)
1        tom2  count(things)
2        bob1  count(things)
3        bob2   count(stuff)
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.  My real dataframe has two more columns in it, say field2 and field3.  I tried running your suggested code with my actual dataframe and it's returning errors.  Do I need to account for the extra columns field2 and field3?

Comment: I believe you need `.set_index(['ReportField', 'col1', 'col2'])`

Comment: Then also column name can be changed, not `level_1` but `level_3`. I am on phone only, so impossible test it.

Comment: Or do you think there are another columns for spliting?